# Java vs Action script which one should i chose to create android applications?

Tags: java, android, actionscript

Actually i am a graphic designer and i need to take a step forward and start learning some programming skills.

What i need to do is to be able to join a team work that produce mobile applications or mobile games.

What do u think should i start learning Flash and action script (I have a little experience with both) or should i start learning java.?

What is the difference between both, cause i know that both are the same way of programming (OOP)

If some one can explain in which case should i use AS and in which case should i use Java.

Thanks,

Comment: I vote to close this question because it's **primarily opinion-based** question.

Answer (score 0):

The language for creating native Android applications is Java.  Some cross-platform systems let you use Javascript (e.g. Appcelerator). As far as I know, there is no way to use ActionScript to create an Android app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but let me explain something, i know that the native language for creating android applications is java, my question is which one is suitable for creating games for example is it Java or Action script not java script .. and what if i would like to create an application with java, can i create the same app using actionscript and flash ? if yes what is the core different between both of them?

Comment: You can use ActionScript 3 to write AIR for Android ( and even iOS ) devices applications ... And there is really many many companies which use AIR to develop mobile apps ...

Comment: _"...As far as I know, there is no way to use ActionScript to create an Android app"_ haha sorry to laugh but its funny in 2015 cos I've been aware of that Flash feature since like around 2011/2012. Even C/C#/C++ can do it. Please see [this snapshot of Flash start-up screen](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/COjKUOSU8AADT_t.png:large). Look at "Create New" section those AIR options allow actionscript code (even for iOS or Android or exe file for PC as example). FlashPlayer on the web seems insecure but outside of the browser, AS3 is up there with native tools